# Solving the Linear Regression Model using QR Decomposition (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-regression

**Background** : I want to implement a MATLAB algorithm that takes as input vectors x and y, solves the linear regression problem
associated with the data stored in x and y using a modified QR version and then to plot the graph of the linear function.

So first I wrote the modified QR algorithm :

```
function x=QRQ(A,b,n)
[Q1,R1]=qr(A);
c1=Q1'*b;
n=length(c1);
x=backward(R1,c1,n);
end
function x=backward(U,y,n)
x=zeros(n,1);
x(n)=y(n)/U(n,n);
for i=n -1 : -1 : 1
      x(i)=(y(i)-U(i,i+1 : n)*x(i+1 : n))/U(i,i);
end
end
```

Then I wrote the algorithm for the linear regression :

```
function ysol = LinearReg(x,y)
A=[x ones(21,1)];
z=QRQ(A,y,2);
ysol=z(1)*x+z(2);
plot(x,y,'bo',x,ysol,'g-');
end
```

I tried to run this algorithm on the following data :

```
x=[0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1;1.25;1.5;1.75;2;2.25;2.5;2.75;3;3.25;3.5;3.75;4;4.25;4.5;4.75;5];
y=[4;3;7;7;1;4;4;6;7;7;2;6;6;1;1;4;9;3;5;2;7];
```

The full error message that I received is :

```
        Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 2).
        Error in untitled>backward (line 12)
        x(n)=y(n)/U(n,n);
        Error in untitled>QRQ (line 8)
        x=backward(R1,c1,n);
        Error in untitled>LinearReg (line 20)
        z=QRQ(A,y,2);
```

The line causing the error is x(n)=y(n)/U(n,n);
the only variable with an index in position 2 is U. Apparently U only has 2 columns, and n is a value >2, hence the error.
Using the debugger, I see that U is a 21x2 array, and n has a value of 21.

How can this MATLAB algorithm be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

The `U` in your case is `R1`. Since the matrix `A` has rank two, `R1` will only have two columns since `A` already only has two columns.
You then try to solve the system `R1 * x = y` using backward substitution with the index starting at `n`, but here you clearly have to start at `2`.

(Keep in mind that `R1` is an upper triangular matrix.)

Comment: So I must fix the for loop for n to start at 2 and define R=triu(A)?

Comment: Yes you should start at 2, but why would you want to use `R=triu(A)`?

Comment: Ah never mind regarding R1, as for the for loop I just loop i=n : -1 : 1?